# what does "@SOME_VALUE@" mean in C++ header

Tags: c++

I've seen something like this in C++ headers:

```
#define VALUE_A @VALUE_A@
```

or

```
#if @VALUE_A@
...
#endif
```

So, could anyone tell me what does **@@** mean?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Those sort of constructs are typically there so that some source code control system (git, mercurial, svn, cvs, etc.) can fill in a value when the file is checked out.  Or, perhaps your build system has some preprocessing that is done to source before compilation.

Comment: Where are you seeing this? (In particular: What header file, what IDE, what platform?)

Comment: @P.Hinker So, you mean @@ is not from C++ but some other things?

Comment: @duskwuff I saw it in [VXL](http://vxl.sourceforge.net/) 's headers - vxl_config.h, for example. And I'm using Eclipse for C/C++ on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Comment: If the package you're using is built on multiple platforms, those sorts of identifiers are used by preprocessors to set architecture or platform specific values.  If you look at the installation/build system you'll find perl or python or other scripts that go through and substitute platform/architecture specific values into those places during the build or installation.

Comment: @P.Hinker I think you're right. The packages([VXL](http://vxl.sourceforge.net/)) actually is for multiple platforms. And it uses Make(or CMake? I don't know) to build itself. I think I should learn Make(or CMake) a little, and perhaps I'll figure it out. Anyway, thank you for your hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you got a source code from other source (not yours) and that is not exactly a `someheader.h` but a `someheader.h.in`

All those `@something@` tags are something that will be substituted by the `configure` script on program configuration.  Just `configure` and you probably get a proper header file with all those `@something@` substituted.

Some reading to `autoconf` info documentation will make you light from darkness.

Comment: Thanks for the hints! After reading that documentation, I will tell you the result - I think it will take a long time.

Comment: It's not necessary to read it all.  You'll get an explanation soon after reading how configuration variables get used at the proper places in files `*.in`.  See doc of  `AC_SUBST` macro.

Comment: Okay. When capture the overview of autoconf, I'll check AC_SUBST out.